# Applying style to value in an object in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have the following map inside my React js file which i am mapping to a select dropdown.

```
 const options = response.map(k => ({
          value: k.id,
          label: k.description ? `${k.name} - ${k.description}` : k.name,
        }));
```

I need to either add a div or apply inline style only to `${k.name}` value. for example i want `${k.name}` to be bold and apply higher font-size value. what is the best way to do this?

Expected Output : https://nimb.ws/sb70xu

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: All you're doing there is returning an array of objects. When you `map` over that JSX you can add className or style to whatever element wraps that property.

Comment: The answers here assume you are using a custom dropdown. If you're using a native `<select>` you cannot apply inline styles to text inside your `<option>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you already have an Option component, you should be able to create a component that accepts the items from the given response as props

```js
const Options: React.FC<Data> = ({ id, name, description }) => (
  <Option value={id}>
    <span className="yourClassHere">{name}</span>
    {description && (
      <span>- {description}</span>
    )}
  </Option>
)

const options = response.map(option => <Options {...option} />);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAERRhTgF44BvUuOYAEwC44AZxhRgAOwDmAGi5xxKEEkEixU2d15IhaMWBjAI4gPwrREyaQC+5LWgA2KInDRGRcIkMjihy+oxQAbQBdWyQHJ1pXH3gAeX1DcUFkdBgAOgAxAGEAHk5uADcUewBXP1ULAG45NAALYHteIiTEYnSUjAA5CC0Q6wA+clJo93iDN2S2zNyGJn7WOAAKdh5eaXlFJHWtHT1x8TgrAEpWecW5HLHEuCLSpBZ2PitB7m4crxQDiKEhTs2WABElAgJSgWUcPwAEkgiAD+uwFEorDkAPQfcQvV7sHa6YAJIxwABkhKWclecHeYE+-QAtBwcXtEsi0VSMWS4EcbG8UVcjIMjuQRvAIPifAtPN5fGkQCgwIsRftThTeWL2Gl1QqmXAUf0jtUgA)

[MUI exmaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-demo-material-ui-forked-yck9eu)

Answer (score -1):

```
const options = response.map(k => ({
          value: k.id,
          label: k.description ? `${<span style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>k.name</span>} - ${k.description}` : k.name,
        }));
```